# Using $this when not in object context? PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have a class in PHP. In the constructor I define a value for a property and then I have to access it in a method. However, I get keep getting `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context`. I need to access the property from within the class.

```
class Base {
    public $vat;
    public function __construct() {
        $settingsClass = new GeneralSettings();
        $generalSettings = $settingsClass->getSettings();
        $this->vat = $generalSettings['vat'];
    }
    public function vatPrice($price) {
        $vatPrice = $price + (($this->vat / 100) * $price);
        return self::formatPrice($vatPrice);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is the problem one?

Comment: You're mixing and matching static and member functions.  Post more code (the caller) and it is easily fixed.

Comment: `$vatPrice = $price + (($this->vat / 100) * $price);`

Comment: In this code you don't invoke `vatPrice` method.

Comment: That's not the caller.  You're calling something like Obj::vatPrice($foo), and you need to do something more like $obj->vatPrice($foo);

Comment: To begin with, dependency inject `GeneralSettings` into `Base` class.

Comment: You may also want to see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6807615/2662489 as just an FYI.

Comment: @inanzzz - Don't confuse the issue.  That isn't what is happening, and isn't necessarily a valid observation without knowing more about how the stack works.

Comment: @John Green - While waiting for more info on OP, I wanted to point out something which would probably be useful in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your class, with a simple value, and I found no errors.

```
class Base {
    public $vat;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->vat = 75;
    }
    public function vatPrice($price) {
        $vatPrice = $price + (($this->vat / 100) * $price);
        return self::formatPrice($vatPrice);
    }

    public static function formatPrice($price) {
        echo $price;
    }
}

$myClass = new Base();
$myClass->vatPrice(100);
```

Note that `formatPrice` is a static function.

---

1. Sometimes you want to refer to some attribute of one instance of the class, only for one object, so in this case you must define an attribute or method of the form `visibility $bar`; for a variable or `visibility function bar($args...)` and you can access with `$this`, because `$this` is the reference of the actual instance of the class (the current object.)
2. Maybe you want to get the same value in some attribute for all
   instances of that class, ie: a static attribute/method. In this case, you have to define `visibility static $bar` for a variable or `visibility function $bar($args...)` for a function and you can access them with the `self` keyword.

*visibility is public, protected or private*

When you have something like:

```
class Foo {
    ...
    public static function bar() { ... }
    ...
}
```

The `bar()` function is invoked as follows:

- Outside of Foo: `self::bar();`
- Inside of Foo: `Foo::bar();`

Conversely, if you have something like this:

```
class Foo {
    ...
    public function bar () { ... }
    ...
}
```

Then,

- Outside of Foo:

you must first instantiate the class, and from that object access the `bar()`:

```
$myObject = new Foo();
$myObject->bar();
```

- Inside of `Foo: $this->bar();`

Please, see the [static keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) reference in the PHP documentation.

Comment: This could be a part of a OOP php tutorial, but i don't see a answer for OP's question

Comment: I'm trying to help fix the error, since he did not have any specific question.

Comment: @Rizier123 haven't Tomas explained how the method must be invoked? SO is not a "fix my code for free" community. And this answer clearly explains what to do to avoid mistake that OP has made.

Comment: @Rizier123 I have run the code and I haven't found any error, then all I can say is that this error occurs when you do not respect what I put in the answer.