# PHP recursion: call to undefined function

Tags: php, function, recursion

The following code gives me the eror`Fatal error: Call to undefined function display() in /srv/http/recipes/classes/controller.php on line 4` 
when I try to access the page

```
class Controller{
    function display($template){
        display('error');
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not trying to call a global function, you're trying to call a class method, so use `$this`: `class Controller{
    function display($template){
        $this->display('error');
    }
}`

Comment: Now sits back and waits for the stackoverflow from the recursive call

Comment: @MarkBaker made my day, of course this function causes an stackoverflow error, I just cut the unecessary parts, now it works.

Comment: also refer [self vs $this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/151969)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change code to this :

```
function display($template) {

   $this->display('error');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `$this` or `self` -

```
class Controller{
    function display($template){
        $this->display('error');
    }
}
```

Or use - `self::display('error');`

Answer (score 1):

```
public function display($template) {

   $this->display('error');
}
```