# Issue with Classes, Instances and Objects

Tags: php, mysql, class, object

I'm fairly new to PHP; however I think I have a good grasp on it, but I'm having an issue understanding why I'm not able to access a second version of a connect to DB class I have.

I connect globally to the first one in a config script.

```
$db = new db(array('login info'));
```

I access it in my controller using the following.

```
public $db;
public function __construct(){
    $this->db = $GLOBALS['db'];
}
```

Then inside my controller I have a function where I create a new instance of this to connect to a different DB.

```
$ordersDB = new db(array('login info'));
```

Now I would like to access each database separately using something like

```
$this->db->select("SELECT * FROM ada Yada
```

and

```
$ordersDB->select("SELECT * FROM Yada Yada
```

However both are still accessing the first db. I know this because I am getting a table does not exist error when executing the second one and it tells me what db its querying. However a var_export of them shows they are infact different! Am I completely misunderstanding how classes work or can I only have one DB open at a time? Thanks for any help.

Edit: Is this what you are looking for?

```
$db = new db(array(connect info));
$controller = new controller();
$controller->connectToSecondDB();

class db {

    public $dbHost;
    public $dbUser;
    public $dbName;
    public $dbPassword;

    public function __construct() {
       $arguments = func_get_args();

       if(!empty($arguments)){
          foreach($arguments[0] as $key => $property){
            if(property_exists($this, $key)){
                $this->{$key} = $property;
            }
           }
       }
    }

  public function connect() {            
        if(!isset(self::$connection)) {       
            self::$connection = new mysqli($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPassword, $this->dbName);
        }
}

class controller {
   public $db;
   public function __construct(){
      $this->db = $GLOBALS['db'];
   }

   public function connectToSecondDB(){
      $ordersDB = new db(array(connect info));
      $ordersDB->select("SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE email = 'email@address.com' LIMIT 1")
      $this->db->query("SQL");
   }
}
```

EDIT Select Query Function

```
private function _sel($table, $where="", $order_by="", $limit="", $group_by="",$database = NULL){
        if($database === NULL) {  $database = $this->db; }
        if($limit == 1){ $single = true; }else{ $single = false; }

        //if( is_array($where) ){ $this->_buildWhere(); }
        $where = (strlen($where) > 0) ? "WHERE $where " : $where;       
        $group_by = (strlen($group_by) > 0) ? "GROUP BY $group_by " : $group_by;        
        $order_by = (strlen($order_by) > 0) ? "ORDER BY $order_by " : $order_by;        
        $limit = (strlen($limit) > 0) ? "LIMIT $limit " : $limit ;

        $sql = "SELECT * 
                FROM `$table` 
                $where 
                $group_by 
                $order_by 
                $limit";
        // Debug

//if(INCLUDE_CHECK){ echo "<HR>".$sql."<HR>";   }
        $results = $database->select($sql); 
        if($single && count($results) > 0 ){
            return($results[0]);
        }else{
            return($results);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you create and post a [short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) that shows the problem in its entirety?

Comment: @VolkerK is this what you are looking for?

Comment: imho a lot of other code is missing in order to find the mistake (e.g. the constructor of db) and please use OO naming convention: class names are concatenated words starting with upper case (e.g. MyClass)

Comment: Looks like your `class db` "hides" a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) inside its constructor.

Comment: @leonixyz I have added the constructor.

Comment: `self::` references the class, not the instance. see [Static Keyword](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) and [Late Static Bindings](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

Comment: @VolkerK What do you mean by that? I have posted the construct function.

Comment: @VolkerK so should I use $this-> instead? This DB class was actually one I found online so it's not my code.

Comment: Don't just copy&paste code. copy&paste&understand is ok.

Comment: @VolkerK :) I thought I understood it fairly well. I read though it to make sure I knew what was going on, but I guess I assumed that self meant that it was just interchangeable with $this->

Comment: You've got the answer. Use `$this->` instead of `self::` It will solve your problem. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-vs-this) for more info.

Comment: @mseifert lol. Thank you I was actually just reading that same post.

Comment: "I assumed that self meant that it was just interchangeable with $this->" It's not ;-) But I'm hesitant to confirm that using $this-> instead of self:: will solve your immanent problem  ...because I'm biased as can be against those one-off, ad-hoc ...grrrr.... database-classes. I have to assume it's one of those "credential-holder + encapsulate the exact same functionality as the underlying api only way,way worse" classes.

Comment: @VolkerK It does work, but I get the warning "Strict Standards: Accessing static property db::$connection as non static"

Comment: You don't show where you declared the class variable $connection,

Comment: @mseifert  it was defined as protected static $connection; I have since removed the static and now the warnings are gone. However. I'm concerned now. With these changes am I making a new connection to the DB for each query I run?

Comment: my function that runs the query looks like this private function _sel($table, $where="", $order_by="", $limit="", $group_by="",$database = NULL){ if($database === NULL) {  $database = $this->db; } So I can use the default unless I need to for a specific situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to reuse your $controller object. Add a `query` method. Then you can run the query separate from the connection method so the controller object can be reused

**You need error checking each step along the way.**

Note that I removed  `$this->db->query("SQL");` as I am not sure what exactly it did. The concept in the answer should get you started redesigning your class.

**UPDATE**
Based on comment, I changed the $db from a super global and passed it to the controller object.

```
$db = new db(array(connect info));
// try passing the $db object so it does not need to be a super global
$controller = new controller($db);
// You can keep your $controller object as a global - I use a session variable for this to reuse it between pages.
$controller->connectToSecondDB();
// run the query separate from the connection so the controller object can be reused
$result = $controller->ordersQuery("SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE email = 'email@address.com' LIMIT 1")


class db {

    public $dbHost;
    public $dbUser;
    public $dbName;
    public $dbPassword;
    public $connection;

    public function __construct() {
       $arguments = func_get_args();

       if(!empty($arguments)){
          foreach($arguments[0] as $key => $property){
            if(property_exists($this, $key)){
                $this->{$key} = $property;
            }
           }
       }
    }

  public function connect() {            
        if(!isset($this->$connection)) {       
            $this->connection = new mysqli($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPassword, $this->dbName);
        }
}

class controller() {
   public $db;
   public $ordersDB;    // ADD THIS

   public function __construct($db2){
      $this->db = $db2;
   }

   public function connectToSecondDB(connect info){
      $ordersDB = new db(array(connect info));
   }

   public function ordersQuery($sql){
      $this->ordersDB->query($sql)
      // Fetch and return you result set here
   }

}
```

Comment: I noticed you still have the "self::$connection = new mysqli($..." is that by design? That is what I changed to get it to work properly. Also all of my DB calls are inside the controller. Meaning I don't ever do a $controller->query because once the controller is done processing there is no need to query the DB again. Does this have basically the same effect as you mentioned?

Comment: Good catch. I was focused on the other changes.  I've updated it to reflect. More changes are still needed. For example, what is `$this->db->query("SQL"); ` supposed to do?

Comment: That was just to show that I was running a query there. I actually have a function inside the controller class that runs all the queries. I have edited the main post to show this function in its entirety.

Comment: Good. You should be able to replace my select with yours and pass the db object to it. Good luck.

Comment: You should realy not rely on superglobals anymore. Pass your DB instance to the constructor. This is a far better aproach

Comment: @DarkBee I totally agree. I should have presented the code to reflect this. I will make this change

Comment: ..and chances are that `class db` should be dropped all together. It doesn't seem to provide any abstraction and if the the remaining methods are as convoluted as the constructor ...just drop it and use e.g. [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo) instead (not a database abstraction either but a reasonably unified access layer).

Comment: @VolkerK - Yes, the db class should be absorbed into the controller class and many more changes besides. But as the user says, they are "fairly new to PHP" and they will figure this out down the road. It would be great to have a SO code repository to point users to and say, Here are a few standard ways to create your abstract database classes.

Comment: I admit that I'm ticked off by `class database { return mysql_query("...$param") }`, `class email { strcpy "\r\n"}` and `class ringbuffer` but on the other hand too lazy to try writing a comprehensive post about those "beginners, _on your level_ those things are solved problems. Don't reinvent it, you will do it wrong. Just use and learn from the existing _solutions_"-thingys. ;-)