# Call to undefined function : Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

### **I have a private function as written below in the Controller.**

```
private function GetProjects($ProjectStatus) {
    return \App\Models\Project\Project_Model
            ::where('ProjectStatusID', $ProjectStatus)
            ->where('WhoCreatedTheProject', auth()->user()->UserID)->get();
}
```

### **Below is the action method that is using this private function.**

```
public function ClientCancelledProjects() {
    $ProjectStatus = \App\Enumeration\Project\ProjectStatus::Cancelled;         
    $MyProjects = GetProjects($ProjectStatus);
    return view("Project.Client.MyProject", array("Projects" => $MyProjects));
}
```

### **Below is the Error coming when running the controller.**

> Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Project\GetProjects()

Somebody knows why this is happening ? I am trying to reuse some lines of code as they are written many times in the Controller.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To access functions in a controller from a function in the same controller, use `self::`:

```
public function ClientCancelledProjects() {
    $ProjectStatus = \App\Enumeration\Project\ProjectStatus::Cancelled;         
    $MyProjects = self::GetProjects($ProjectStatus);
    return view("Project.Client.MyProject", array("Projects" => $MyProjects));
}
```

Note: `Self::` (uppercase) will work depending on the version of `php` installed, but for older versions, `self::` is preferred.

Please check this link for more info: [PHP - Self vs $this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-vs-this)

Answer (score 10):

Functions inside of a class are not global functions, and cannot be called that way. You need to use `$this->GetProjects()` instead.