# PHP Equivalent of JavaScript "this" keyword, specifically within an object?

Tags: javascript, php, class, object, this

In JS, when defining an object, if one of the object properties is a function, using the `this` keyword within that function will return the current object you are working under. This is useful if you'd like to retrieve the values of other properties within the same object.

For example:

```js
// Javascript Code
var val = 'I never get seen.';

var o = {
    val: 'I do get seen!',
    fun: function() {
        // use `this` to reference the current object we are in!
        return this.val;
    }
};

// Outputs 'I do get seen!'
console.log(o.fun());
```

However, I can't figure out how to do the equivalent in PHP. I'm running PHP 5.6, so I have access to anonymous functions. Here is my sample code:

```php
<?php
// PHP Code

$val = 'I never get seen.';

$o = array(
    'val' => 'I do get seen!',
    'fun' => function() {
        /**
         * I've tried:
         *
         * return $this.val;
         * return $this->val;
         * return $this['val'];
         * return this.val;
         * return this->val;
         * return this['val'];
         *
         * None of them work.
         */

        return $this->val;
    }
);

// Should output 'I do get seen!'
echo $o['fun']();

?>
```

**EDIT:**

As others are pointing out, I "should" be using a real class, and access the classes properties that way.

However, in the code I am working in, I do not have the luxury to making that paradigm change. If there are no alternative options, I'll keep in mind that there isn't an exact one-to-one equivalent for this idea within PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use self over $this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-over-this)

Comment: you should note that PHP actually hass the `class` keyword to define a class. not everything is an array.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if your approach is correct. In PHP, `$this` is used within the context of a class/object.

Comment: PHP and JS are different languages. Not everything is an object...

Comment: In the code example that  you posted, `echo $o['val'];` should give you what you are looking for. You may still get some other syntax error though.

Comment: @Maximus2012, it is entirely possible (and likely) my approach is wrong. I'm much more used to JS than PHP. Just trying to figure out how it would look in PHP to try and do something similar.

Answer (score 3):

How to define a class in PHP:

```
class test {
  private $val = "value";
  function fun() {
    return $this->val();
  }
}
//instantiation:
$obj = new test();
echo $obj->fun();
```

PHP is a language that actually supports classes and does not have to trick by using arrays for everything

Comment: JS has classes, though prototypal, a class syntax was recently introduced to the language spec.

Comment: I admit, that choice of words was a little polemic, but I don't think we have to start a discussion about the weird things that JS does and doesn't do

Comment: romellen, this is the correct answer to your question, you could do a favor by marking it as such.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that you cannot just use all the things in one language (JS) and "convert" it to some other language (PHP). You could actually come close by [using anonymous classes](https://3v4l.org/rR7P4):

```
<?php

$o = new class {
    public $val = 'I do get seen!';

    public function fun() {
        // use `this` to reference the current object we are in!
        return $this->val;
    }
};

var_dump($o->fun());
```

Whether you should do this... I highly doubt it.

Different languages (especially prototype based and classical OOP based languages) just do things differently.

Comment: I know not all features of one language exist in others, I was asking if in this case, this feature _does_ exist. 

Thanks for the reply though, it is helpful.