# why is the output of the php program?

Tags: php, class, object

I am learning Classes and Objects of PHP, but these codes confuses me:

```
<?php
class A
{
    public function test()
    {
        //output will be A load(), why?
        self::load();
        //output will be B load(), why?
        $this->load();
    }
    public function load()
    {
        echo "A load()";
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function test()
    {
        parent::test();
    }
    public function load()
    { 
        echo "B load()";
    }
}
$c  = new B();
$c->test();
```

In these situation, why `self::load()` and `$this->load()` get different output?

Please describe with detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use self over $this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-over-this)

Comment: because `self::load()` references the `load()` method of the __class where the method is called__ in the inheritance tree; whereas `$this->load()` references the load method of the __instance__, and by inheritance the `B` `load()` method is overriding the `A` `load()` method for the instance

Answer (score 5):

It's because `self` use the class it belongs to as it was defined. The whole thing is documentationed here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

There is a different between using `self` and `static`. Be aware with your code, normally the method test needs to be defined as static for calling it with `self::test();`.

Answer (score 0):

so lets start.

`Self` choose current class.

`this` chose current object.

so when you use `self::load();` it load function in class A

in the other hand when you use `$this->load();` it mean `class B->load`