# PHP | Access to undeclared static property

Tags: php, class, static

After trying several attempts at this for some reason i get the error `Access to undeclared static property` when i try to make an object out my class.

My class:

```
final class repo {
    var $b;

    /**
     * @var \Guzzle\Http\Client
     */
    protected $client;

    function repo($myvar)
    {
        static::$b = $myvar;
        $this->client = $b;
    }
}
```

Me making an object:

```
$myobj = new repo("test");
```

Comment: `$b` isn't a static propriety. `$this->b = $myvar` or `public static $b;`

Comment: You must initialize $b as **public static $b** . Unless you cant use it.

Comment: `var $b;`. You want to support php4? Or you just read very old tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare $b as static variable.

Also note that method as a class name is deprecated now [see the details here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

```
final class repo {
    public static $b;

    /**
     * @var \Guzzle\Http\Client
     */
    protected $client;

    function repo($myvar)
    {
        static::$b = $myvar;
        $this->client = static::$b;
    }
}
```

Comment: why did you change `static::$b = $myvar;` into `$this->b = $myvar;` then?

Comment: @Federkun Both are same, It is a member of class so I have used `$this` but we can also use scope resolution to achieve the same. Is there any issue ?

Comment: have you tried it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-over-this

Comment: thanks @Federkun for explanation. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration `var $b;` is PHP 4. PHP 5 allows it and it is equivalent to `public $b;`.

However, it is deprecated and if you use a proper error reporting ([`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) during development) you get a warning about it. You should use the PHP 5 [visibility kewords](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) instead.

Also, the declaration `function repo($myvar)` is a PHP 4 constructor style, also accepted but deprecated. You should use the PHP 5 [`__constructor()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) syntax.

You access `$b` as `static::$b` and this is not compatible with its declaration (equivalent, as I said above, with `public $b`). If you want it to be a class property (this is what `static` does) you have to declare it as a class property (i.e. `public static $b`).

Putting everything together, the proper way to write your class is:

```
final class repo {
    // public static members are global variables; avoid making them public
    /** @var \Guzzle\Http\Client */
    private static $b;

    // since the class is final, "protected" is the same as "private"
    /** @var \Guzzle\Http\Client */
    protected $client;

    // PHP 5 constructor. public to allow the class to be instantiated.
    // $myvar is probably a \Guzzle\Http\Client object
    public __construct(\Guzzle\Http\Client $myvar)
    {
        static::$b = $myvar;
        // $this->b probably works but static::$b is more clear
        // because $b is a class property not an instance property
        $this->client = static::$b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
final class repo {
    public $b;

    /**
     * @var \Guzzle\Http\Client
     */
    protected $client;

    function repo($myvar)
    {
        $this->b = $myvar;
        $this->client = $this->b;
    }
}
```

Note: static::/self:: is used on static functions.