# Why my php class does not save it's property?

Tags: php, class, oop

Consider this sample code

```
<?php
class MyAwesomeClass {
    public $myawesomeproperty = 'test';

    public function __construct() {
        $self = new stdClass();

        $self->myawesomeproperty = "hello guys!";
    }
}

$test_obj = new MyAwesomeClass();

echo '<pre>';
var_export( $test_obj );
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

It's supposed to set "myawesomeproperty" to a new string so var_export shows "hello guys!" in the output.

What I'm actually getting is

```
MyAwesomeClass::__set_state(array(
   'myawesomeproperty' => 'test',
))
```

Apparently the construct function does not save anything to actual object.

Why is this happening? What am I missing?

Comment: Do not use "short open tags" they are long deprecated and very server-specific. Always open your code with `<?php`.

Comment: Why are you doing this `$self = new stdClass();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the property of a local variable called `$self`. If you want to change the object's property, use `$this` instead:

```
<?php
class MyAwesomeClass {
    public $myawesomeproperty = 'test';

    public function __construct() {
        $this->myawesomeproperty = "hello guys!";
    }
}

$test_obj = new MyAwesomeClass();

echo '<pre>';
var_export( $test_obj );
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Ok, you are right, I mistakenly used "$self->" thinking it would work like "self::" but with public properties, 
now [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-over-this) actually cleared my mind completely.Thanks for your answer. The most stupid mistakes are so obvious when pointed at :D

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a different object ($self) inside the constructor. You aren't doing anything with it, so the object is removed from memory when php leaves the function scope.

To overwrite a property of the object attached to the current function scope, use `$this->myawesomeproperty="Hello Guys";`