# Which is best $this or self or static when referencing const variable?

Tags: php, static, this, constants, self

I learned that **static** is better than **self** because self does late static binding.

But I wonder which would be best at referencing **const** variable.

```
class Black
{
    const color = 'black';

    public function byThis()
    {
        return $this::color;
    }

    public function bySelf()
    {
        return self::color;
    }

    public function byStatic()
    {
        return static::color;
    }
}
```

I checked all of three getters work well. Which is the best choice? (I use PHP 7.0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use self over $this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-over-this)

Comment: They're not the same if you create a subclass that redefines the constant. `byThis()` and `byStatic()` will return the subclass's value.

Answer (score 7):

Keywords `self` and `static` are different in this way:

```
class White {
    const color = "white";

    public function byThis()
    {
        return $this::color;
    }

    public function bySelf()
    {
        return self::color;
    }

    public function byStatic()
    {
        return static::color;
    }
}

class Black extends White
{
    const color = "black";
}

$black = new Black;
echo "byThis: " . $black->byThis() . PHP_EOL;
echo "bySelf: " . $black->bySelf() . PHP_EOL;
echo "byStatic: " . $black->byStatic() . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
byThis: black
bySelf: white
byStatic: black
```

I would expect output to be `black` with `$black` instance, so `static` is better in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The PHP [class constants documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.constants.php) recommends the use of `self::` for a constant within a class. I personally would stay with this.

Every one of the keywords return the same value, even if the class extends another class with another value for the constant, except for `parent::` which returns the value of the parent class:

```
class White {
    const color = "white";
}

class Black extends White
{
    const color = "black";

    public function byThis()
    {
        return $this::color;
    }

    public function bySelf()
    {
        return self::color;
    }

    public function byStatic()
    {
        return static::color;
    }

    public function byParent() {
        return parent::color;
    }
}

$black = new Black;
echo "byThis: " . $black->byThis() . PHP_EOL;
echo "bySelf: " . $black->bySelf() . PHP_EOL;
echo "byStatic: " . $black->byStatic() . PHP_EOL;
echo "byParent: " . $black->byParent() . PHP_EOL;
```

The output would be:

```
byThis: black
bySelf: black
byStatic: black
byParent: white
```

Comment: Yes, but no - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9c3b8895568b596ded6e0c10fcb4efa658221cd0

If the methods are in the parent class, things are very different