# Using self:: instead of $this

Tags: php, static, static-methods

i came by some php code where the developer who wrote it is being a little contradictory i think.
so here is the code he wrote:

```
if ($this->SQL !== null && $this->SQLState === self::STATE_CLEAN)
        return $this->SQL;
```

where the SQLState and the STATE_CLEAN are defined like this:

```
class someClass {
    const STATE_CLEAN = 1;
    private $SQLState = self::STATE_CLEAN;
}
```

so you can see that for some class attributes he uses $this and for some he uses self:: and i can't understand why.
can any one help. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use self over $this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-over-this)

Comment: not possible because i know what they both mean, i just don't understand this  specific case.

Comment: Guess I don't understand your question then. Can you explain more?

Comment: he is purposely using both self:: and $this while he can use $this instead, actually he should use none of the defined attributes are static? so i think either he is inconsistent with his code or he knows something i don't know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
private $SQLState = self::STATE_CLEAN;
```

The property is initialized to the value of the constant.

At some point, the property may change, but the constant is *constant*. So checking for this condition:

```
$this->SQLState === self::STATE_CLEAN
```

makes sense to verify that the current state is the same as the initial state.

---

To clarify since I think I missed the main point of the question, `self::STATE_CLEAN` is used because `STATE_CLEAN` is a [class constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php). Using `$this->STATE_CLEAN` will get you

> Notice: Undefined property: someClass::$STATE_CLEAN

Comment: why not using $this->STATE_CLEAN instead of self::STATE_CLEAN

Comment: @Dever In which part he should've used `$this->STATE_CLEAN` instead of `self::STATE_CLEAN`?

Comment: both actually while none of them are static why using self::

Comment: @Dever `STATE_CLEAN` is a constant, you can't access it using `$this`

Answer (score 1):

Good practice is to:

use 
`self::` for class constants 
(when refering class - you could have no initialized object instance of this class)

and `$this->` for class variables 
(when refering initialized object instance)