# Which option should be choosed in this context, self, static or this. Does it make any difference?

Tags: php, oop, static, this, self

The PHP docs explain about the Scope Resolution Operator (::) that it is for use mainly in static contexts along with self, static and parent.

But then you find that it's possible to use it instead of $this regardless static context or not, as in this example:

```
class A {
   public function funA() {
      self::funB();  // *Works*
      static::funB();   // *Works*
      $this->funB();  // *Works*
   }
   public function funB() {
   }
}
```

Is this a PHP design issue or am I misunderstandig something? I find the use of ::, static, and self a little confusing... When to choose one or other?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/151976/9921075 I suggest you look at this answer :)

Comment: @Ezabilam but then some of the options should thow an error depending on the context, because it leads to confusion...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use self over $this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-over-this)

Answer (score 1):

PHP Manual explained this in [Late Static Bindings](https://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) although perhaps it is not as concise as it should be.
Allow me to offer my own explanation.

Here is the guideline:

> - `self` always refers to the class where the word `self` appears.
> - `static` always refers to the current class in static context, even if the class is extended.
> - `$this` always refers to the current class in object context, even if the class is extended.

As shown in the following example, use `self` if you want to always refer to class A,
use `static` and `$this` if you want to always refer to class B, when B is the current class.

```
class A {
    public function test() {
        echo self::who();   // always class A
        echo static::who(); // always the current class (static context)
        echo $this->who();  // always the current class (object context)
    }
    public function who() {
        echo __CLASS__ . "\n";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function who() {
        echo __CLASS__ . "\n";
    }
}

(new B)->test();
```

Output:

```
A
B
B
```

As you can see, `static` and `$this` refer to the same class (class B).
Let's extend the example with another class that extends class B:

```
class C extends B {
    public function who() {
        echo __CLASS__ . "\n";
    }
}

(new C)->test();
```

Output:

```
A
C
C
```

Notice that `static` and `$this` refer to the same class again, class C this time,
because `static` and `$this` always refer to the current class, even if the class is extended.

So what is the difference between `static` and `$this`?
The difference is the context.
`$this` requires an object (a class instance), while `static` does not.

Let's see what happens if `test()` is called in static context:

```
C::test();
```

Output:

```
A
C

Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 7
```

The first and the second calls work fine in static context but the third call fails because `$this` requires object context.
See the code in action at https://ideone.com/AVtITz