# Stubbing child methods fails when testing parent method

Tags: php, mocking

In the example below, `loadTargets()` correctly returns its assigned stub value when directly called. But when called using `self::` inside a parent method it then tries to run the actual, non-stubbed method and fails.

Is there a way to have it work the same as when it is directly called? I thought that a partial mock would do just that.

```
public function testQueryDbForNewSelection() {
  $adminUtilitiesMock = Mockery
    ::mock('AdminUtilities[loadTargets]');
  $adminUtilitiesMock
    ->shouldReceive('loadTargets')
    ->andReturn(17);

  codecept_debug($adminUtilitiesMock::loadTargets());  // 17

  codecept_debug($adminUtilitiesMock->parentFunc()); // [PHPUnit\Framework\Exception] Undefined index: limit  
}
```

Also tried: (same error)

```
public function testQueryDbForNewSelection() {
  $adminUtilitiesMock = Mockery
    ::mock('AdminUtilities')
    ->makePartial();
  $adminUtilitiesMock
    ->shouldReceive('loadTargets')
    ->andReturn(17);
```

And also:

```
codecept_debug($adminUtilitiesMock::parentFunc()); // [PHPUnit\Framework\Exception] Undefined index: limit
```

Here are the 2 method declarations. My desired behavior is for  `loadTargets()` to be ignored and overwritten by the stubbed value `17` during the invocation inside `parentFunc()`.

```
 public static function loadTargets() {
    global $wpdb;

    $query = $wpdb->get_results(
      "select * from {$wpdb->prefix}fvc
        limit {$_POST['limit']}
        offset {$_POST['resultMarker']}
    ");

    return $query;
  }


  public static function parentFunc() {
    $data = self::loadTargets();
    codecept_debug($data); // does not print to console, probably due to crashing out on the above line
    codecept_debug('=====$data=====');        
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing `self::` to `static::`

```
  public static function parentFunc() {
    $data = static::loadTargets();
    codecept_debug($data); // 17
    return $data;
  }
```

[When to use self over $this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-over-this)

> DO NOT USE self::, use static::
>
> There is another aspect of self:: that is worth mentioning. Annoyingly
>   self:: refers to the scope at the point of definition not at the point
>   of execution.