# How to get the const/ static properties of a PHP class

Tags: php, reflection

I am developing a PHP application. Now, I am trying to loop through all the static/ const properties of a PHP class maybe through reflection.

I have a class like this

```
class MyClass
{
   const MY_CONST = "my_const";
   public static $MY_STATIC_PROP = "my_static_prop";
}
```

What I want to do is that I want to loop through all the properties of a class and check if the name of the property is equal to something.

```
if ($property_name == "something") {
    //do something
}
```

How can I do that in PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use self over $this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-over-this)

Comment: Maybe just `property_exists`?

Answer (score 0):

To get `private` and `public` properties you can use [**get_object_vars()**](https://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) and for `const` and `static` properties can use [**ReflectionClass()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) class object. Finally merge all the properties. Example:

```
class MyClass
{
    const MY_CONST = "my_const";
    public static $MY_STATIC_PROP = "my_static_prop";
    public $pub = 'Pub';
    public $pvt = 'Pvt';
}

$ref = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');

$allProperties = get_object_vars(new MyClass) + $ref->getConstants() + $ref->getStaticProperties();

foreach ($allProperties as $name => $vale) {
    if ($name === 'something') {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```